# xampp apache wont start after oracle db 10g is installed. how to fix?

Tags: database, oracle, apache, xampp, port

I've been doing php before but as usual,I used mysql as a database. So everything seems easy when using xampp.

Now, for some reason I am required to use Oracle as the database but after installing Oracle database 10g on my pc, I can't seem to start apache from the control panel at all!  When I press start,instead of it being started it goes back to the stopped state. I tried making it a service and starting it from, it pops out an error.

What is making this conflict, I can use IIS to do this but I prefer xampp so I'm eager to make this thing work.

Does anyone know whats the conflict?  Is it the port?

I know how to configure the oracle extension and all with php to get it to work, but I am just confused why apache can't be started when oracle db 10g is installed.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: There is a certain danger in using prepackaged Apache/PHP/MySQL things like XAMPP. I always build and install everything myself.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem with startup.pl not starting (according to the log files), so I went into xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf and editted out this include line by putting a hash (or pound as it is called in the states) (#) in front of it:

Perl settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-perl.conf"

it seems to work now and I have now got oracle and apache working on my machine.
Im not sure if there will be any problems later on because of removing the line, but I don't think I need to use anything perl related so hopefully it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like platform is Windows. Oracle has the habit to alter the PATH setting, system wide. There is also an Apache installation in the Oracle installation. Maybe you can tweak the Apache service to use the Oracle Apache installation. Otherwise, make sure that your Apache start service does not have ORACLE_HOME or sub-directories of ORACLE_HOME/bin in the PATH. The services that Oracle installs normally are not on the standard ports so it's not very likely that it is a port conflict.